# lookupPostParam returns always Nothing

Tags: yesod, yesod-forms

In the Home.hs handler from the yesod-simple scaffold I added these lines to postHomeR:

```
fileDescriptionMaybe <- lookupPostParam "fileDescription"
let result = fromMaybe "(empty)" fileDescriptionMaybe
```

Then in the homepage.hamlet template I use this result with  the variable interpolation '#{result}'.

However the result is always "(empty)".
How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you trying to submit the parameter?

Comment: I've not tried to submit the result as a parameter. How do I have to do that?

Comment: You'd usually create a POST form. I'd recommend trying out the forms chapter in the Yesod book.

Comment: fileDescription is already a form field in the Home.hs created with yesod-simple, and available in homepage.hamlet. However, I want manipulate a copy of this field (called it result), with Haskell code in Home.hs, before it is submitted. May be I was not clear on that. I've studied the forms chapter but got stuck on this.

Comment: Result is also submitted, since I can pick it up with the variable interpolation #{result} in homepage.hamlet. However it seems I can't use lookupPostParam within the postHomeR handler.

Comment: It's not really possible from the information you've provided to figure out why it isn't working. Have you looked in Firebug and/or Chrome Tools to see what the POST body actually contains?

Comment: I checked it with Firebug and found that result is not in the POST but in the response. I gues I can't use lookupPostParam in the form's POST handler since there is nothing submitted yet. But then my question is: how can I do something, for example convert (for example with Haskell's toUpper), with a POST parameter after it is submitted, using lookupPostParam. I've searched for examples but couldn't find that.

Comment: I feel I know enough for this moment to find my way myself in this stuff. The firebug tip have helped with that. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Found that instead of lookupPostParam "fileDescription" I need to use lookupPostParam "f2" ...